# How to read POST or GET request from a web server that using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, get

I'm working with a third party developer that using CodeIgniter to send data using Curl from his web server into my web server.

My web server is using regular (not using PHP framework) PHP. And I usually use these PHP command to read POST or GET from different server:

1. $argv
2. file_get_contents('php://input')
3. isset

I tried to use **$argv** but did not catch anything, well I usually using it to read GET parameter from cronjob (So it might not work with other).

**file_get_contents** also give me nothing.

**isset** also cannot detect if a GET or POST parameter being set.

I even wrote two scripts to test if my codes are working. Using regular php Curl command, I can send and receive the data flawlessly from a webserver into another web server.

Do I miss something here?

Is there any specific way to read a data that being sent from CodeIgniter using curl into a regular (not using framework) PHP web server?

Any help, like link to related question or an answer would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: there's no such thing as `Codeigniter framework web server`

Comment: `$argv` is for reading CLI arguments (when PHP is called through CLI), not GET or POST data (when PHP is called through a web server). Use `$_GET` for query params and `$_POST` for post data.

Comment: @swadhwa 
Ah, what I mean is web server that using CodeIgniter. Gonna edit my question a bit.

Comment: Codeignier or core php has no role on how these http requests are sent or read

Comment: the other developer might be making improper curl request from his server. if content-type header is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you should be able to read the request body with $_POST. but if not, or maybe set to `application/json` then `file_get_contents('php://input')` should work

Comment: `file_get_contents('php://input')` should get you the response body in any case, regardless of Content-Type - _if_ there was one to begin with. // Did you not talk to them and agree upon which data format they are sending upfront?